# How do I integrate a java client with an android application

Tags: java, android

Ok just to give a background I have a WCF service and I've made a client for it in java using MyEclipse 10.0. Now basically the client needs to reside on an android device and it just struck me that I might not be able to port it. I have absolutely no experience (of course I've got the HelloWorld app running though) with working on android. Also what I had in mind was that I'd create an applet in java for the client but I'm presuming awt wont work in android. I've seen that the android toolkit for designing an app is quite good so I dont mind working with it. But all that is bothering me is how do I integrate the java client which includes a lot of imported class especially from the javax.xml package. Any suggestions on how I can move forward will be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately you cannot use Java classes in Android. Check out http://javathings.blogspot.com/2009/03/java-applications-j2me-on-android.html. I think there are some "runners" that can run some Java in Android but, Android, by default cannot simply import any Java classes and run them. You would have to port.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. Android SDK is an extension of Java core SDK. So you can use any class from Java by importing the Libraries (Jar files) in Android Project. Unless the library is any hardware specific it will work well with Android too. (Not all, Most of them).

For example if you use an API to call a web service in Java, you can use the same in Android by adding that Library to your Application.

Comment: Ok so is the best option to recode the client in android from scratch or do I try to do some patching up with the java classes to make them fit in android? Im sorry but I've sort of got conflicting replies here

Comment: No you could use your existing code if you put your client as a library of your android project.

Comment: Ok I guess I've got an idea of how to proceed. I will get back if I have more issues. Thanks!

Comment: I exported my java web service client as a jar file and included it in the library of my android application. I am now able to refer to most of the classes from the client but I am still getting this error

The type javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Anything I've missed out?